# Golang problem with multi generics functions call

Tags: go, generics

I want to fetch config from remote and cache the result. The api have two data structs but process in same way. So I use generics in process functions, and when cached data is different with remote config, update cache data，but I got the error in function saveKeyStore, `old != new (incomparable types in type set)`,Here is my code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "sync"
)

var m sync.Map

type AccountResponse[Payload AppleKeyStore | GoogleKeyStore] struct {
    Data struct {
        Options Payload `json:"options"`
    } `json:"data"`
    Code int `json:"code"`
}

type AppleKeyStore struct {
    KeyID           string `json:"kid"`
    SharedPasswords []struct {
        BundleID string `json:"bundle_id"`
        Password string `json:"password"`
    } `json:"shared_passwords"`
}

type GoogleKeyStore struct {
    AuthProviderX509CertURL string `json:"auth_provider_x509_cert_url"`
    AuthUri                 string `json:"auth_uri"`
    Bucket                  string `json:"bucket"`
}

func getCachedKeyStore[Payload AppleKeyStore | GoogleKeyStore](appID string) (*Payload, error) {
    value, ok := m.Load(appID)
    if ok {
        t := value.(Payload)
        return &t, nil
    } else {
        return nil, errors.New("cache keystore not exist")
    }
}

func saveKeyStore[T AppleKeyStore | GoogleKeyStore](appID string, old, new T) {
    if old != new {
        m.Store(appID, new)
    }
}

func fetchRemoteAccount[Payload AppleKeyStore | GoogleKeyStore](accountID string) (*AccountResponse[Payload], error) {
    urlStr := ""
    client := &http.Client{}
    params := url.Values{}
    params.Add("id", accountID)
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, urlStr, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    req.URL.RawQuery = params.Encode()
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", "token"))
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("fetch secret api, response status code: %d", resp.StatusCode)
    }
    var appleAccountResponse AccountResponse[Payload]
    err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&appleAccountResponse)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &appleAccountResponse, nil
}

func getKeyStoreFromRemoteOrCache[Payload GoogleKeyStore | AppleKeyStore](accountID, appID string) (*Payload, error) {
    remoteAccountRespone, fetchErr := fetchRemoteAccount[Payload](accountID)
    cachedKeyStore, getCacheErr := getCachedKeyStore[Payload](appID)
    if fetchErr != nil {
        if getCacheErr != nil {
            return nil, errors.New("fetch account failed and get cache apple account failed")
        } else {
            return cachedKeyStore, nil
        }
    } else {
        saveKeyStore(appID, *cachedKeyStore, remoteAccountRespone.Data.Options)
        return &remoteAccountRespone.Data.Options, nil
    }
}

func main() {
    getKeyStoreFromRemoteOrCache[GoogleKeyStore]("", "")
}
```

I tried to define Generic interface, but it seems generic type cannot extend from other generic type, or golang can not inter the struct type AppleKeyStore to comparable type.

Comment: I think go generics are not `Comparable` types so you can not use the `==` on them as struct can contain map or slices etc. One way to do it is create interface for keystore and write equals method with type checking and equality. Which in turn gives you more flexibility so you can check agianst custom types and maps and slices manually. Let me know if you need sample example I will provide that.

Comment: [Here is simple example](https://goplay.tools/snippet/JofmPdSwr3J) how I would do it you need to modify the equality for apple store since it contains the inner slice struct.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a generic function, it must compile for all possible values of its types. The `saveKeyStore` function is valid for `GoogleKeyStore`, but not for `AppleKeyStore`, because `AppleKeyStore` is not comparable: it has a slice in it.

You might consider writing an `IsEqual` method for both types, and use a constraint that requires the types to have `IsEqual` method.

Comment: At this point you're not really using generics anymore, you're using a traditional go `interface`.  So you can remove all your generics and replace with `KeyStore` interface type.